# How many m values are there for the 4f sublevel. In high school so no fancy words please!

Tags: electrons, orbitals, electronic-configuration

How many m values are there for the 4f sublevel? In high school so no fancy words please!

Answer (score 3):

With no fancy words:
The **orbital angular momentum quantum number** $ l $ is given by the letter you see there: **f**. Remember that we link this quantum number with integers in the following fashion:

1. $ l = 0 $: sublevel s.
2. $ l = 1 $: sublevel p.
3. $ l = 2 $: sublevel d.
4. $ l = 3 $: sublevel f. So we got it, $ l = 3 $.

How many orbitals we have? Well, we have $ 2l + 1 = 2\cdot 3+1 = 7 $. These seven orbitals are numbered from the value $ -l $ to $ l $, so you can list them in the following way:

$$ m = \{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ,3 \} $$

Remember these $ m $ values are the **magnetic quantum numbers**. Sometimes you may find them with the symbol $ m_l $.

Comment: Huh, "orbital angular momentum quantum number" could be some "fancy words". You sure you wanted answer this thing in particular ;)

Comment: Everything is written in fancy words, except the names for $ l $ and $ m_l $... I didn't put those names! But that's how the OP will see them in the exam, for sure!

Comment: I was being snarky about OP's question, not the answer. This looks like one that a mod could have already closed if he saw it. But, well, you can answer what you want... I just recommend being a bit more picky in the future ;)

Comment: I will, I am new to the site, but I just like to help. Thanks